# Ms Access DB used by website

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have been asked to update a legacy website.

I was originally build in asp using a MS Access DB to store some user details.

However I am aware that the DB can be downloaded if you use the correct url.

What is the best way to stop this without stopping the website having access to the DB?
Thanks
Sp

Comment: You should really move to a more appropriate database engine. Jet/ACE is not really designed for this kind of purpose, even though under low load and the right circumstances it can work just fine.

Comment: I agree, the db is very small but holds login details so i need to make it safe and then look at making the site future proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the database outside the website directory, then refer to it by "../../Data/something.db" or setup a DSN entry in the ODBC manager

Comment: If you do this, be sure that the Web Host account has access to the location with the MDB file.

Answer (score 3):

Put the database outside the public html folder. Server side code should still be able to access it.